# C# - Launch a process in a different directory of the executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process

I need to launch a process that is for example in this path:

```
c:\A\ApplicationToBeLaunched.exe
```

I want that this process runs in a different path of their executable. This other folder will have all the configuration files of the ApplicationToBeLaunched.exe application. For example, the path could be:

```
c:\B\
```

I am trying to do this with this c# code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process prProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
prProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\A\\ApplicationToBeLaunched.exe";
prProcess.StartInfo.UserName = "";
prProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\B\\";
prProcess.Start();
```

But the process always is executed in the application directory `(c:\A\)`. I also have tried to set the property `UseShellExecute` to true.

What am I doing wrong? Can any help me?

Editing:

After some tests, I have checked that the issue is in the application launched. The process with the working directory is working fine.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It is unclear from what I can read.

Comment: What do you mean by "executed in the application directory?" Do you mean that the working directory for the process isn't set, or is something else unexpected happening? Is your `ApplicationToBeLaunched.exe` something you've written yourself?

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary for what seems like a simple scenario like yours, but maybe try using Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I have checked that is working fine. Exist another problem in that application launched by the new process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did a little test, created a small program with this in the Main method:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process prProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        prProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\src\Test\ObjectTest\ObjectTest\bin\Release\ObjectTest.exe";
        prProcess.StartInfo.UserName = "";
        prProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        prProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\temp\";
        prProcess.Start();
```

And in the ObjectTest.exe

```
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

And the output result:

```
c:\temp\
```

So i think your having some other problem with your program and not problem with the WorkingDirectory.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked that is working fine. Exist another problem in that application launched by the new process.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `WorkingDirectory` is not working but I have encounter this by myself in the past.

Try to change the current working directory before starting the new process:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("c:\\B\\");
```

Comment: Thanks, I have checked that is working fine. Exist another problem in that application launched by the new process